# Google Maps Autocomplete - Find autocomplete HTML to use as jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps, autocomplete

**TL;DR** - Does anyone know what the ID to the dropdown menu for Google maps Autocomplete is?

---

I am using Google Maps in a form on my site. I would like to use jQuery to kindly remind the user to select an option from those listed in the autocomplete options that Google gives you. If the user clicks in the input, but does not select one of the options, I would like to then show the notification.

However, I can't seem to find the ID to the list of options that pops up. (Or div, or other HTML for that matter.) Nothing appears in the elements for these options.

For example:

[image: Google Maps Autocomplete]

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<label for="title" class="form-title">Location</label>
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Street Address</label>
    <input type="text" id="formatted_address" name="formatted_address">
  </div>
  <div id="my_map"></div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**
*Libraries*

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY&libraries=places&language=en"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/geocomplete/1.7.0/jquery.geocomplete.min.js"></script>
```

*Code*

```
      $("input#formatted_address").geocomplete({
          details: "form",
          map: "#my_map" });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you including `jQuery UI`?. jQuery doesn't have an autocomplete "widget". jQuery UI's [autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) has a `select` callback. You can use the `event` parameter in this to find the list item, and finally it's ID. Not 100% sure, but something like this should work: `var selected_item_id = $(event.target).attr('id');`

Comment: @AlmostPitt  try my solution

Comment: Are you using the Google Maps Javascript API v3?  An embedded Google Map? (what does the code for the map look like?)

Comment: @AaronEveleth, No, Google Maps itself has the autocomplete widget. But you had a good idea. I've tried something similar as well. I'll post it above.

Comment: @geocodezip, yes I belive I am using Google Maps Javascript API v3. It is an embedded map. I'll post the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Add Listener to your Autocomplete input element.This will fire
whenever user select option from dropdown of Autocomplete list

```
//Declare variable to identify option from autocomplete selected or not
var selected_from_autocmp_flag = false;

address_element = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("#input_element_id"));
address_element.addListener('place_changed', place_changed);

function place_changed(){
  // set flag to true 
  selected_from_autocmp_flag = true;
}

$("#input_element_id").click(function(){
  // set flag to false whenever user clicks it
  selected_from_autocmp_flag = false;  
})
```

**Assuming you have input element in HTML page as below**

```
<input type=text id="input_element_id" placeholder="search here"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Krishnar. Unfortunately, I get the errors: InvalidValueError: not an instance of HTMLInputElement and Uncaught TypeError: a.getAttribute is not a function.

Comment: @AlmostPitt Brother did u pasted as it is?   u should replace you element id in place of input_element_id.   Check i updated code.

Comment: Good question. No, I changed it to add the correct ID. Actually, now I can see that I get "formatted_address" when I click that input box, but then "undefined" when I select one of the options. I still have the errors, though.

Comment: @AlmostPitt This should work. Tell me if any concern/doubt how to use

Comment: Yeah, do you mind helping me use it? I keep getting these errors: "Uncaught TypeError: a.getAttribute is not a function" and "InvalidValueError: not an instance of HTMLInputElement"

Comment: @AlmostPitt show your html form where you have defined input search

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156891/discussion-between-almostpitt-and-krishnar).